# Image not showing after getting from canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using Vue and need *the files to preview before upload*, if file is image then reduce its size (using canvas) and display, else just display the extension of file using canvas, so I have done something like this:

```
// I have used this function in the html like <img src={{ imagePreviewURL(File) }} />
imagePreviewURL(File) { // <-- get the uploaded file
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')!; // <-- create canvas
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')!;
  canvas.width = 100;
  canvas.height = 100;
  if (File.type.includes('image')) { // <-- if file is image
    const image = new Image(); // <-- create new image
    image.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100); // <-- draw image to canvas
    };
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(File); // <-- set source of image
  } else {
    ctx.font = '30px Arial';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(`.${File.name.split('.').pop()!}`, 50, 55); // <-- just display extension
  }
  return ctx.canvas.toDataURL(); // <-- convert canvas to image
}
```

The extension part works very fine, but the image is not showing.

Comment: `image.onload` is async it isn't going to run before you `return ctx.canvas.toDataURL()` therefore your image isn't drawn to the canvas before the function returns.

Comment: Can you give the solution to this?

Comment: How to async await it?

Comment: Instated of file send the event and call like -: This method is prefixed in Chrome and Webkit as window.webkitURL.createObjectURL().
You should test if URL exists and then use the appropriate object:

(window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL(evt.data);

Comment: @LDS already done this.

Comment: `function imagePreviewURL(file) { 
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  const canvas = /*[...]*/
  if(file.type.includes('image')) {
   const image= new Image();
   image.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100);
      canvas.toBlob((blob) => resolve(URL.createObjectURL(blob)));
   };
   image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  } else {
    ctx.font = '30px Arial';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(\`.${file.name.split('.').pop()}\`, 50, 55);
    ctx.toBlob( (blob) => resolve(URL.createObjectURL(blob)));
  }
}`